# html5/css3 custom shape button with multiple colors

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: button with multi color]

I need help for attached button css.
can any one help me to do css or guide me ?

Comment: Have you tried anything Or searching anything?

Comment: No i am searching. do you have any idea like this ?

Comment: Check: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-gradient-border/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a combination of mask and linearGradient in an SVG as CSS background image to achieve an effect like this.

#### it works like this

you can use 100% width and height within your SVG. But unfourtunately the stroke extends outside of shapes, so if you stroke your 100% rect the stroke ist partitialy outside of your viewport. That does not look very nice. the trick is to have a second rect which serves as a mask for the fist rect which has a slighly smaller stroke-width, effectively cutting out the parts that otherwise would be outside the viewport.
Now you can just stroke the rect with a gradient to get the result you want.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <linearGradient x1="0" y1="1" x2="1" y2="1" id="lg1">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="red" />
    <stop offset="0.2" stop-color="red" />
    <stop offset="0.2" stop-color="blue" />
    <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="blue" />
    <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="green" />
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="green" />
  </linearGradient>

  <mask id="m1">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" rx="40" ry="40" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" />
  </mask>

  <rect stroke="url(#lg1)" stroke-width="40" mask="url(#m1)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" rx="40" ry="40" fill="none" />

</svg>
```

Comment: I appreciate with you answer but can we create a button like filter button which is shown in image ?

Comment: as i said, use the image above as a background image in css